# Parentheses affecting operator precedence in java

Tags: java

```
class test8{
    static public void main(String args[]){
        int d = 9;
        d += d = 3;
        System.out.println (d);
    }
}
```

My understanding was the expression inside parentheses evaluates first setting `d` to `3`.

So, the above expression is equivalent to
    `d = 3`
    `d+= 3` which should give `6`.
How does java evaluate this to `12`.

Comment: I don't see the parentheses you talk about in the code you posted.

Comment: int d = 9; 9+3 = 12. Where are parentheses?

Comment: I tried d += d = 3 which yields 12. This is clear to me. I also tried d += (d = 3). Ideally the sub expression in parentheses should get evaluated first as parentheses have highest priority. So, this one translates to d = 3; d+= 3; which should give d = 6

Answer (score 1):

```
int d = 9;
d += d = 3;
```

First `d = 9`. Then `d += d = 3` which means:

```
Let `d` equal to `d` plus the result of `d=3`.  
                  ^                      ^
                  9                      3
```

So let `d` equal to `9` plus `3` which is `12`.

Answer (score 0):

d is evaluated to nine first and when you change it to three the shortcut add operator adds new value of d which is 3 to old value of d which was 9

Answer (score 0):

Paranthesis in Java as in other languages have a really significant role and that is why you get some issues because of not paying attention

You may see this line of code:

```
  d += d = 3;
```

As:

```
 d = d + 3
```

The first d is from the += operator and the 3 is from saying d = 3

Comment: I tried d += d = 3 which yields 12. This is clear to me. I also tried d += (d = 3). Ideally the sub expression in parentheses should get evaluated first as parentheses have highest priority. So, this one translates to d = 3; d+= 3; which should give d = 6.

Comment: well yo are right.the parantheses get evaluated first but after the initialisation .so that is why d(1)+=(d(2) = 3) you first evaluate the attribution then the paranthesis.WHat i mean to say is that first the JVM sees d is going to get evaluated to "something" let's keep this in mind then as it goes through it sees :hmmm  i have a paranthesis better evaluate it[it evaluates it to 3] and then does the operation is was suppossed to

Answer (score 0):

You expression is `d+=(d=3)` evaluated next way

1. evaluate `+=` expression (which is shortcut to `d = d + (d=3)`
2. evaluate `d + (d=3)` expression to evaluate it first evaluate left side `d` which have value 9 then right side
3. evaluate `d=3` which have value 3 and side effect
4. continue step 2 we have `9 + 3`
   5 assignment `d = 12` which erase previous `d` value

Comment: I tried d += d = 3 which yields 12. This is clear to me. I also tried d += (d = 3). Ideally the sub expression in parentheses should get evaluated first as parentheses have highest priority. So, this one translates to d = 3; d+= 3; which should give d = 6

Comment: `+=` is not an ordinary operation. It is sortcut to `int tmp = d; d = tmp + (d=3)`